# Missing File After Destroying KVM

Tags: mount, filesystem, kvm-virtualization

I am using virsh to manage my KVMs on Ubuntu 14.04. I store my disk path targets (.IMG files) on an LV and mount it manually.

I, of course, forgot to mount this LV after a restart but virsh was still able to start my KVM. Surprising, but ok.

While the KVM was running I mounted the LV. Everything was still ok. Then when I destroyed the KVM my disk image disappeared.

How did my disk path target (disk image) disappear? Any way to recover it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had saved my img file to right path but wrong device (forgot to mount after restart so it was on my OS device). Thus when I mounted by kvm image device this file was hidden. Found it by accident when I unmounted the device.

This [response](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41336/where-do-the-files-go-if-you-mount-a-drive-to-a-folder-that-already-contains-fil) helped to clarify what I was doing wrong.